# Error while installing update

Tags: apt, updates, sudo, dpkg

I am very new to ubuntu. I have Installed today only. I tried to update software by typing comnmand in Terminal as

```
pranay@Hom-lnx:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade 
[sudo] password for pranay:
```

after giving password I am getting this Error

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

I tried to search on forum but could not find helpful link..Please provide some suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Kindly restart your system. Because your administration directory is locked by other process. So a restart would do the miracle. Hope it helps!

Comment: @Avinash Raj Doing so would remove the lock and hinder the process flow thus, this may lead to fatal error. It is strictly avoided when you are working with production system.

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf 

sudo apt-get update
```

it will resolve your problem.